# What is the maximum version of PHP that Joomla 1.5 will run?

Tags: joomla-1.5

I have a client with an old Joomla 1.5 they dont want to upgrade this year but their host wants to upgrade the server. What is the maximum version of php that Joomla 1.5 will run rather than the min that is listed?

```
http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html#footnote-1xPHP
Joomla! versions 1.5.15 and later are compatible with PHP 5.3.
```

Would it run ok on 5.3.10? I would guess it would break on 5.4 but I find it hard to build a test machine with old versions to test. So more question from experience.

thanks

Comment: Please dont point out I should upgrade it though as there is a different budget for that later, thanx

Comment: But a small advice: Maybe a small WAF(Web Application Firewall) like AdminToolsPro can save much of your time and money :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running Joomla 1.5.14 or **below** then you should stick to PHP 5.2 as there may be a few functions and/or code snippets that may not work on PHP 5.3

However, if you're running Joomla 1.5.15 or **above**, you should be fine with upgrading to PHP 5.3. If you're using the OpenID library, then this won't be compatible with PHP 5.3 and thus you will either need to find an alternative or stick with PHP 5.2

For more information on which versions of PHP, MySQL and Apache, have a look at the[Technical Requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html)

I would suggest you upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26 which is the latest version of the 1.5 series.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just for completeness as well Joomla 1.5 is not compatible with PHP5.4 at any version

Comment: I have a few Joomla 1.5.26 websites running fine on Joomla 5.4. although I did need to disable the strict standard errors as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/9984309

Comment: Don't forget the unofficial security patch: http://anything-digital.com/blog/security-updates/joomla-updates/joomla-15-security-patch-made-easy-to-install.html

Comment: I have quite a few Joomla 1.5.26 patched / 1.5.999 sites running on php 5.4.28, just disabled the strict warnings.

Comment: Omly Joomla 1.0 has problems with PHP 5.3 (there is a unofficial patch to use J1.0 with PHP5.3) and Joomla 1.5 work with PHP 5.4.x.

Comment: If those that have J1.5 sites running on PHP 5.4 are sure that every single feature works fine and doesn't produce any errors then I would suggest contacting whoever maintains the Joomla site and get them to update the Technical requirements. May I also suggest you write an answer for the OP

Comment: The project hasn't officially tested 1.5 on PHP 5.4 so we don't make the statement that it is supported.  This is why PHP 5.3 is the recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running a Joomla 1.5.26 site alongside a new J3 site under construction on the same PHP installation. The J1.5 site is running perfectly on PHP 5.6 without any changes to anything at all. The J1.5 site is a very simple site with only a few extensions.

Comment: Yes, sorry it should read 1.5.26.

Comment: Just confirming I now have several varied Joomla 1.5.26 websites running fine on PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm Joomla 1.5.24 running on PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17. PHP-FPM was installed with apt. Web server is nginx. All features seems to be running smoothly.